# New Custom ROS Messages Not Found (But Old Ones Still Found)

Tags: python, ros, catkin

Quick Notes: Programming the main_gui in Python and this is being done on a Windows machine.

I have 2 packages ("main_gui" and "my_ros_messages") and one package (my_ros_messages) has custom messages that are used by the other package (main_gui).  my_ros_messages has approximately 66 messages that main_gui been using for a while without any issue.

I needed to add 2 more custom messages so I did the following:

- Added the ".msg" files for each into the msg folder in my_ros_messages package (along with the other 66 messages that were already there).
- I added the filenames to the "add_message_files()" in the CMakeLists.txt in the my_ros_messages package.
- I added the import to the main_gui package script file (right after the other imports for the previous messages it has already been using).
- I changed nothing else.

When I tried doing a new build (catkin_make), main_gui still imports the previous 66 messages fine but doesn't import the two new messages. I get the following error for the new one:
ImportError: cannot import name 'ConfirmSetParam' from 'my_ros_messages.msg'

What is confusing to me is that the others still work fine but the 2 new ones don't work.
I've tried the following to resolve but none worked:

- I verified that I didn't misspell any of the filenames, extensions, and so forth
- I deleted the entire "build" folder for the workspace so that everything needed to be rebuilt from scratch and did another catkin_make (btw, I'm not forgetting to source the devel\setup.bat ... remember this is on a Windows machine)
- I have it setup to where the my_ros_messages package is built prior to the main_gui and my_ros_messages is a dependency of main_gui (listed in  generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...) in main_gui CMakeLists.txt)
- I saw that the new message header files are being generated in workspace /devel/include/my_ros_messages/ folder (along with all the other previous 66 messages).

Does anyone have an idea why this isn't working?  If the entire thing is working properly and I simply add 2 more messages to the current working group, why don't these work?

Comment: I know you deleted the build folder. But, just to see if this is a caching problem, you could try to rename the `message`-package to something else, e. g., `A`. Then, try to build the package `A` and see if you can import the new messages from there.
Also, you could try a `catkin_make clean` and then rebuild. Does this help in any way?